# Накладные расходы SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Хотелось бы узнать, насколько затратно открытие и закрытие `SQLite` в `Android`. На пример есть `ViewPager`, в котором в каждом фрагменте отображается какая-либо информация из таблицы в базе. Что в таком случае будет разумнее - перед созданим `ViewPager` грузить всю таблицу(если она не очень большая) или каждый раз при создании фрагмента - открывать соединение, грузить информацию только для данного фрагмента и закрывать соединение?

Comment: хорошей практикой считается получать данные по мере надобности, а не таскать везде все в куче.